# How to keep figures and captions on their own separate page while text flows on the page before and after in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am writing a thesis and the formatting requires that when a figure name is mentioned, that figure must appear on the next page by itself with its caption. However, the text from the rest of the document must flow continuously from the previous page to the page after the figure.

Is there an automated way to make this happen?

I would essentially like to be able to anchor the caption to the first time the figure is mentioned (using cross-referencing so that the numbers update as needed) and makes the figure appear on the page after it by itself.

I have tried searching online and have not seen a good solution for this issue, but I do not want to edit the formatting manually as small changes to the text can require the entire project to be reformatted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following workaround, which might not be the prettiest one, but at least it helps a bit:

1. Create a style for your images, modify it and in the bottom left of the style settings, click on "Format" > "Paragraph...", switch to the "Line and Page Breaks" tab and activate "Page break before", then save the style.
2. Set the image layout option of your image to "In Line with Text"
3. Apply the newly created style to this image. This will push the image automatically to a separate page
4. Apply the newly created style also on the paragraph after the image caption. This will push that paragrah also to the next page.

This is really as much as you can do in Word. Alternatively, you could also create a 1-row table with invisible borders and make the table a full page size high. Then make sure that you don't allow line breaks for that table. Like that, the table will always stand alone on a separate page and you don't have to bother with the paragraph that comes after the table, as it will be automatically pushed to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : Sorry, but this is not possible.

One would normally use a wrap option on such option for text to flow with/around an object, but you cannot have a wrapped figure
as the only object on a page - any wrapped object must be anchored to a text paragraph.

You're asking for the object's anchor to float to the next page,
but that's not possible. Anchors just don't do that.

In addition, you would need to find out exactly where in the flowed paragraph you need to place the anchor.

I suggest to finish writing the entire thesis, then do the
formatting manually on the very final version.